# Url.Action fora da Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Separei o cadastro de usuário do asp.net mvc em uma área

Area Controle

Em uma action, de cadastro, ele envia o link de confirmação, o mesmo é gerado da seguinte forma

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Ao receber o email, ele fica a Url assim:

```
http://localhost:50855/Controle/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId..
```

Ele acaba pegando o nome da área, sendo que a Account está fora da área

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só explicitar que a `Action` não usa `Area`:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code, area = "" }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Comment: te devo mais uma kkkk te mandar uma caixa de bera HUASHDU

Comment: Daqui a pouco vira um caminhão, hein?

Comment: [Ou então usa esse link aqui](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=58B8G88A995VJ).